# Why does adding salt to the water in a humidifier increase the amount of steam it makes?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, evaporation, phase-diagram

[image]

Rather than "it decreases the latent heat of vaporization", can you explain *why*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular humidifier works by sending electric current through the water using a pair of immersed electrodes. This makes the water hot and starts it boiling. If the water were completely ion-free, it would not conduct electricity and the water would not be heated, producing no steam.

So if your tap water is very pure, the humidifier will not work until you add some salt to the water. It then becomes conductive, experiences ohmic heating, and boils into vapor.

Comment: So does this humidifier also produce hydrogen and oxygen by electrolysis at the electrodes?

Comment: No, just steam.  remember it's running on AC, not DC.

Comment: Very interesting! So I guess one of the pro features of this design is that it is fail safe - if it runs dry then it can not overheat. Thanks!